# How to Convert 3 way table to a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this dataset:

```
df <- structure(list(sez = c("1_1_1", "1_1_1", "1_1_1", "1_1_3", "1_1_3", 
                          "1_1_4", "1_1_5", "1_2_1", "1_2_1"), class = c(1, 5, 5, 3, 
                                                                         2, 4, 6, 6, 7), sex = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
                                                                                                      2)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to get a three way frequency table, so I use:

```
xtabs(~ sez +sex+ class, data=df)
```

To organize data in a better and readable way,  I use ftable function:

```
mytab <- xtabs(~ sez +sex+ class, data=df)
ftable(mytab)
```

In order to get an object with the same layout of ftable I try in this way:

```
newdf <- as.data.frame.matrix(mytab)
```

Unfortunately, it gives me the following error: Error in `[.default`(x, , i) : wrong dimension number.

Can someone help me with this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe this could help ? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462769/converting-an-ftable-contingency-table-to-a-dataframe-in-r

Answer (score 0):

What `class` would you like `newdf` to be?

If you want a `data.frame`, you can use:

```
newdf <- as.data.frame(ftable(mytab))
```

Which gives us:

```
   sez sex class Freq
1 1_1_1   1     1    1
2 1_1_3   1     1    0
3 1_1_4   1     1    0
4 1_1_5   1     1    0
5 1_2_1   1     1    0
6 1_1_1   2     1    0
```

Comment: Hi @Matt, thank you for your answer. Actually I would obtain an object equal to that shown by ftable, that is: sez in row, sex in column (with both 1 and 2  modality for each value of sez;  and class in column, with the distribution of cases related to sex modalities. In my case it' would be better output than what I can get using your solution because I have to work on a large database and then export the results in a csv file.